# Customise Actionbar how can i achive?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

i want to show two images in action bar without listing in **menu.xml** file 
means i want to customise with **image button or button** and i want to set background color in action bar i want to try with onCreateActionView() this method can any one provide me deep knowledge ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

design a layout as per your need and use the code

> `actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.test_action);`

and u can use the buttons or images by finding its id from the action bar.

Comment: can you give me some example link so i can try